# Drop Down value contains question mark in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my html and js code for the angularjs dropdown .

js code

```
$scope.yearValues=[
    {
        label : "Year 1 - 1/17 - 6/17",
        code : "Year 1 - 1/17 - 6/17"

    },
    {
        label : "Year 2 - 6/17 - 9/18",
        code : "Year 2 - 16/17 - 9/18"
    }
  ]
```

html code

```
  <select name="FiscalYear"  ng-options="myYear.label as myYear.label for 
   myYear in yearValues" ng-model="mylYear">
  </select>
```

Everything is working fine when I am running in my local but when I move this code to development environment dropdown value contains question mark .

in Develop env wherever - is there it is replaced with three question mark ,

example

dev Env :

```
   year 1 ??? 1/17 ??? 6/17 

   year 2 ??? 6/17 ??? 9/18
```

but It should come like this

```
    Year 1 - 1/17 - 6/17

    Year 2 - 6/17 - 9/18
```

how to solve this issue ? waiting for you guys suggestion ....

Comment: add <meta charset="UTF-8"> in page

Comment: Your app works fine : http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28306/

Comment: The issue is due to encoding the special characters. add <meta> tag in your html

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `Character Encoding` type inside of your html code.

> **What is Character Encoding?**
>
> ASCII was the first character encoding
>   standard (also called character set). ASCII defined 127 different
>   alphanumeric characters that could be used on the internet: numbers
>   (0-9), English letters (A-Z), and some special characters like ! $ + -
>   ( ) @ < > .
>
> ANSI (Windows-1252) was the original Windows character set, with
>   support for 256 different character codes.
>
> ISO-8859-1 was the default character set for HTML 4. This character
>   set also supported 256 different character codes.
>
> Because ANSI and ISO-8859-1 were so limited, the default character
>   encoding was changed to UTF-8 in HTML5.
>
> **UTF-8 (Unicode) covers almost all of the characters and symbols in the
>   world.**

for more information refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp).

Please use as following meta tag inside of your `<head>` tag.

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

complete example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> //<-- see the tag      
  <title>Character Encoding</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1> Year 1 - 1/17 - 6/17 </h1>
  <h1> Year 2 - 6/17 - 9/18 </h1>
</body>

</html>
```